# how to create a custom tree similar to the back office category one in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, category-tree

I'm trying to create a left menu like the category one in a custom module to display my own hierarchy. I want to use a custom model from a custom table.

[image]

I was able to get the category tree in my module by adding the following files :

- vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/templates/tree.phtml
- Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tree.php

Now I want to edit the content and I can't find how.
I tried to modify the getSuggestedCategoriesJson() method with no success.

Can anyone help me?